# how to find absolute speed,distance,speed from source and destination of google map in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am unable to get proper absolute distance from source to destination on google map.

```
return location.distanceTo(dest latitude and longitude);
```

and also i used

```
distanceBetween() 

distance2 = distanceBetween((Location) newMarkerList.get(0));
```

but I am not getting the correct result; any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method for that in Location class - [check here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween(double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float[]))

If that's not working it means you are either expecting incorrect values or are not passing the right ones.

Comment: for checking purpose i just passed static latitude and longitudes for source and destination.for distance between hyderabad and ongole is 329000m.The distanceto() method returns distance in meters.but i am not getting correct result.it returns 28356 something like that,

Comment: That distance from distanceTo() is in straight line. Are you looking for routed distance on roads between 2 points?

Comment: no,can u tell me how to find routed distance on roads between 2 points,i 'm not having any idea regarding that

Comment: Routed distances are not part of the SDK for several reasons, but most important there are no maps included in Android SDK. You can use Google Directions API which comes free for 2500 calls/day - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

Comment: Actually, depending on the quality of results you are expecting there is another free one (as far as I recall)  http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open/directions-service